# Weird behavior in combobox C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a weird behavior in my combobox. I have two combobox, one is cboSede an the other is cboGroup. CboSede enable cboGroup. I have already done this in other forms but here I get this message: ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code. The idea is if the user does not choose any value in cboSede then cboGroup is not enabled and in the other hand, if the user choose a valid option in cboSede, cboGroup is enable.

This is my code:

The SelectedIndexChanged of cboSede

```
private void cboSede_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Util.Security.ConexionBD)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(cboSede.SelectedIndex) == 0 || Convert.ToInt32(cboSede.SelectedIndex) == -1)
            {
                cboGroup.Enabled = false;
                cboGroup.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this.FillGroupCombo();
                cboGroup.Enabled = true;
            }

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Warning",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
```

the FillGroupCombo function

```
private void FillGroupCombo()
    {
        try
        {
            Entity.Group objGroup = new Entidad.Group ();
            objGroup .IdSede = Convert.ToInt32(cboSede.SelectedValue);
            objGroup = Control.Group.ListBySede(objGroup );

            if (objGroup != null && objGroup.ListGroup.Count > 0)
            {
                Entity.Group objMsje = new Entity.Group();
                objMsje.IdGroup = -1;
                objMsje.Name= "--- Select group ---";
                objGroup.ListGroup.Insert(0, objMsje);
            }
            else
            {
                Entity.Group objMsje = new Entity.Group();
                objMsje.IdGroup = 0;
                objMsje.Name= "-- No groups found --";
                objGroup.ListGroup.Insert(0, objMsje);
            }
            Util.Utilitario.FillCombo(objGroup.ListGroup, this.cboGroup, "IdGrupo", "Name");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Util.Security.Insert(ex);
            Util.Security.SaveLog(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any idea about why this happens?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception

Comment: I might have read it fast but `SelectedIndex == 0` means that the first element in the `ComboBox` is selected. In the first code sample it looks like you treat this condition as nothing being selected. // Also you do not need to `Convert.ToInt32` the `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: the line is -> cbe Group.SelectedIndex = 0

Comment: Check your data to make sure you are not binding null values.

Comment: change this line to check for `<= 0` `if (Convert.ToInt32(cboSede.SelectedIndex) == 0 ||` get rid of the OR `||` conditional check

Comment: Apparently your `cboGroup` does not contain items.

Comment: As I say is a weird behavior because is not an error is more like a warning because if  I continue with debugging, the combo fills with "Entity.Group" so I guess the combo has elements but they do not show appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(cboSede.SelectedIndex) == 0 || Convert.ToInt32(cboSede.SelectedIndex) == -1)
{
    cboGroup.Enabled = false;
    cboGroup.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Will kill the code when `SelectedIndex == -1` and you actually have **no item** in your `comboBox` (when `index = 0`, it is `OutOfRange`)

you can give an `if` condition if you want

```
if (cboGroup.Items.Count > 0)
    cboGroup.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This way, it first check of the `comboBox` really have anything. And if it doesn't then it won't produce `OutOfRange` error

Comment: Glad to hear that. But though you do not get `OutOfRange` error, you may still want to figure out why the `ComboBox` has no item at all. Is that expected?

Comment: As I say is a weird behavior because is not an error is more like a warning because if I continue with debugging, the combo fills with "Entity.Group" so I guess the combo has elements but they do not show appropriately @Ian

Comment: I see. I think if it doesn't have Items.Count > 0, likely (I suspect) it really has nothing at all. Perhaps you may need to check on this too. But glad that at least you are not stuck because of the `OutOfRange` error.